# MobileFirst: Handling Binary Responses in React Native

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm new to MobileFirst development. I need to download a zip file from one of the adapters. I am able to do this when invoking REST API call eg using Postman. But I'm not sure how to handle this when using MFS sdk:

Here's my code to access the adapter:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url,
    WLResourceRequest.GET
  );
  const resp = await resourceRequest.send()
```

I log the response and it's showing special characters in the responseText.

Is there a way to handle the binary response?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For any binary content, you will have to convert the content to Base 64 in your adapter and revert it back to binary in your app. 
This is because the WLResourceRequest APIs are designed for handling text based data.

If your binary content is rather large, then it is best to host the file somewhere and return the link to the file from your adapter.